# accessing .name.name attribute of excel cell while iterating over usedrange

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to iterate over the used range in a worksheet and match the given .name.name attribute to a cStringBuilder for future use in a web application.

But I'm running into errors with the append function and using the .name.name attribute of a cell.

If I use something like `Worksheets("MAIN").Range("F2").name.name` I extract the correct information. But it doesn't work will the for loop.

If I use `cell.name`it does however extract the correct cell values. But I have to match a .name.name attribute as I can't be sure on exactly where in the sheet the data is presented always.

The error message I'm getting is: `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`

Here's my coding that I'm trying to make work.

```
Public Function Testing() As cStringBuilder

Dim strJson As cStringBuilder
Set strJson = New cStringBuilder

For Each cell In Worksheets("MAIN").UsedRange
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        strJson.Append (cell.name.name)
    End If
Next
Testing = strJson
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each cell In Worksheets("MAIN").UsedRange

    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print cell.Name.Name

Next cell
```

This seems to work for me, if there isn't a name, you'll get an error.

Comment: Thank you, the `on error resume next`fixe my problem. I didn't think of that. Really appreciate it!